# PHPStan configuration for FuelPHP

Tags: php, fuelphp, phpstan

I am having a lot of trouble getting PHPStan to see the FuelPHP core classes. It would appear this sort of thing causes it grief:

```
namespace Fuel\Core;

/**
 * Template Controller class
 *
 * A base controller for easily creating templated output.
 *
 * @package   Fuel
 * @category  Core
 * @author    Fuel Development Team
 */
abstract class Controller_Template extends \Controller
{
    /**
    * @var string page template
    */
    public $template = 'template';
```

Where Controller is also in the Fuel\Core namespace:

```
namespace Fuel\Core;

abstract class Controller
{
    /**
     * @var  Request  The current Request object
     */
    public $request;
```

It looks like PHPStan can's find Controller because it is looking in the root namespace. FuelPHP gets around this (magic? autoloading? aliasing?). Is there a way to get PHPStan to jump on the same bandwagon, or do I need to stub out all the core classes I'm using?

Comment: The fuel autoloader aliases all "core" namespaces to the root, to make it easy to create your own version or to overload the core version of the class. Most IDE's have a similar issue, I have a classes.php in the project root that contains lines like  
    class Agent extends Fuel\Core\Agent {}
    class Arr extends Fuel\Core\Arr {}
    ....

so my IDE can find them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to follow this guide? [PHPStan: Discovering symbols](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/discovering-symbols)

I helped set up FuelCMS analysis in the past. What worked for that user was this `phpstan.neon`:

```yaml
parameters:
    scanDirectories:
      - core/classes

    bootstrapFiles:
      - core/classes/autoloader.php
```

There's an example repository that works: https://github.com/ondrejmirtes/phpstan_problem/tree/fix

For some reason the `phpstan.neon` is buried in `app/classes/controller` while it should definitely be in the root directory. But otherwise it works.